# Integral of differential forms $\int (-y+\sin x^2)dx + xdy$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, greens-theorem

I should calculate

> $$\int (-y+\sin x^2)dx + xdy$$

on the curve $c=c_{1}+c_{2}-c_{3}-c_{4}$ where it doesn't give me any parametrisation mappings; only the normal 
$$
\begin{cases}
c_{1}:& [0,1] \rightarrow R^{2}, c_{1}(t)= (t,0) ,\\
c_{2}:& [0,1] \rightarrow R^{2}, c_{2}(t)= (1,t) ,\\
c_{3}:& [0,1] \rightarrow R^{2}, c_{3}(t)= (t,1) ,\\ 
c_{4}:& [0,1] \rightarrow R^{2}, c_{4}(t)= (0,t) . 
\end{cases}
$$
should I just use them, for example, for $c_{1}$: $\int^{1}_{0} \sin(t^2)dt $ or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why "the normal" ? you want $\int_c$ so do as you said. What about green's theorem!

Comment: I meant we normally get that curve c for a singular 2-cube but in addition, we get a parametrizing mapping, for example, $(t_{1},t_{2})$ $\rightarrow$ $(t_{1}^{2}, t_{1}t_{2}, t_{2}^{2})$ which we use to do the integral. So should I just calculate the integral above? because we're not supposed to know how to solve such integrand. Also, what about Green's theorem?

Comment: This smells like Green

Comment: Could you elaborate more, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With direct way**
$$\int_{c}(-y+\sin x^2)dx + xdy=\int_{c_1}\sin t^2dt + \int_{c_2}dt - \int_{c_3}(-1+\sin t^2)dt - \int_{c_4}0dt=2$$
where all integrals are on $[0,1]$.

**With Green's theorem**
$$\oint_{\partial D}(P\ dx+Q\ dy)=\iint_D \left ( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) dx\ dy$$
where $D$ is the area of the region, that is $=1$, then
$$\int_{c}(-y+\sin x^2)dx + xdy=\int_{D}\ 2 dx\ dy=2$$

Comment: Thank you, it appears to be quite easy to calculate using Green's theorem.

Comment: Of course green is better here and you are welcome.